# VB SaveFileDialog if cancel then

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, savefiledialog, cancel-button

When the user presses the "Cancel" button in SaveFileDialog I want to rename a textlabel.

```
Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    Label6.Text = "Saved!"
End sub
```

This is working for the "Save" Button. I don't know how to do it for the "Cancel" button.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using that event, why not compare the result returned from the `ShowDialog()` method?

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok
    Label6.Text = "Saved!"
Else
    Label6.Text = "Cancelled!"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the use of cases for something like this

```
Select Case SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Case DialogResult.Ok
        Label6.Text = "Saved!"
    Case DialogResult.Cancel
        Label6.Text = "Cancelled!"
End Select
```